# wildcard in path name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, pattern-matching, wildcard

There are updates for 32-bit and 64-bit systems everyday on my company's server.
I have to copy the latest folder update to a location `C:\Latest\`. The path where updates take place looks like this:

> ```
> \\serv1\everyday\abcd\x64_00-0123-2068\
> \\serv1\everyday\abcd\x86_00-0123-2077\
> \\serv1\everyday\abcd\x64_00-0122-2067\
> \\serv1\everyday\abcd\x86_00-0122-2076\
> \\serv1\everyday\abcd\x64_00-0121-2066\
> \\serv1\everyday\abcd\x86_00-0121-2075\
> \\serv1\everyday\abcd\x64_00-0120-2065\
> \\serv1\everyday\abcd\x86_00-0121-2074\
> ...
> ```

So basically I have to copy the latest (by date and time) `...\x64_00...\disk\system` folder everyday. How can I write a batch script for this? How can I use wildcards for folders names?

I have tried this:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir "\\serv1\everyday\abcd\x64_*\Disk\system\" ') do robocopy /MAXAGE:1 %a C:\Latest\.
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This website isn't a place to go when you want someone else to write an entire program for you. If you have a specific problem about some kind of program you wrote which isn't working as intended, then that's a perfect question for this site. If you haven't even started yet, then I suggest you go attempt something first before coming here seeking assistance.

Comment: for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir "\\serv1\everyday\abcd\x64_*\Disk\system\" ') do robocopy /MAXAGE:1 %a  C:\Latest\

Comment: Please add this information to your question so that others can see

Answer (score 1):

You can use global wild-cards like `*` and `?` in the last element of a path only.

The following approach is probably what you are looking for:

```cmd
pushd "\\serv1\everyday\abcd" || exit /B 1
for /F "delims=" %%D in ('
    dir /B /A:D /O:N "x64_*"
') do set "LATEST=%%~D"
robocopy "%LATEST%\Disk\system" "C:\Latest" /MAXAGE:1
popd
```